# Outlook won't let me create signatures

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, email-signature

Our company has just implemented a multi-factor authentication policy for all email addresses after an attempted hacking, which has worked fine on all computers apart from one.

**Problem:** Among the many and varied issues with this one computer's Outlook (don't start me) is that although we have managed to get Outlook functioning, it won't let us create signatures. Apart from the mandatory company signatures, the user in question relied on a range of email signatures basically as template emails, and really needs them back.

**Symptom:** when attempting to add a signature to an email no options come up, apart from the button 'signatures' to edit or add a signature. Clicking on this, outlook pauses for a bit as if it's working in the background, but nothing more ever comes of it. The same happens if you try to access the signatures dialog box through File > Options > Mail > Signatures.

**Attempts to fix**; We've tried the office repair tools, both quick repair and online repair, multiple times with a restart in between. We've also tried manually uninstalling office and reinstalling it. I then tried a solution I found online that involved searching Regedit for `0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046` and deleting all corresponding registry keys - still no luck.

**Other possibly related issues:** the same computer's outlook has a few other issues which I'm attempting to fix (at least, hoping a fix for one will catch those issues as well!!) including:

- When adding the user's personal company account `Username@companyname.co.uk`, it creates another folder in outlook called `Accounts | Companyname` as if the accounts email address has also been added. Probably a whole new question going to be added to the site about this. EDIT: [here it is](https://superuser.com/questions/1662927/outlook-ghost-email-account).
- Various company programs such as our order-entry system now refuse to output anything to email, saying 'Cannot create ActiveX component'. This is pretty serious as this user is doing 90% of the accounts and debt-chasing for the company.
- Less significant but still annoying; when clicking on an email in outlook, the preview pane is now noticeably loading much slower, a matter of 4-6 seconds maybe. Doesn't sound a big deal, but irritating for someone dealing with hundreds of emails a day.

It's been going for about a week now, anyone who can provide a fix or fixes to this mess has my eternal gratitude.

Comment: I've had the signature happen many times with Outlook 2016. It turned out that deleting "Microsoft Office Desktop Apps" from the "Windows Apps" resolved it (so the "new" app list in windows, not via configuration panel). Maybe the same thing is happening to you. Obiously if your version of Outlook is via a subscription, this doesnt apply.

Comment: Thanks @silbee for the suggestion, but it hasn't worked when I tried it just now.

Comment: What's the specific version of your Outlook client(File>Office account>About Outlook), have you checked if there are any differences between this client and others? I haven't experienced same issue but as a suggestion, in order to avoid the interference of add-ins or other programs, it's recommended to close other programs and restart your Outlook in safe mode to check(windows + r>type"outlook.exe /safe">enter)

Comment: Thanks @Jade, tried that but it has made no difference. WE've checked the 'about' section you suggested but it doesn't mean much to me - looks like standard Office365 outlook, Version 2106 - checked for most recent updates too.