# Outlook 'ghost' email account

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

Sorry about the title, I didn't know how else to describe it.

Among the issues I've had with one particular computer since our company enforced multi factor authentication (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1662913/outlook-wont-let-me-create-signatures) for another question about it) is that when adding a certain users account, a new folder is created (as if another email address has been added).

- The new folder is called `Accounts | companyname` and appears as a separate folder even when the `accounts@companyname.co.uk` email address is added to outlook as well.
- Right-clicking the folder, the 'file location' option is greyed out, and clicking 'remove' brings up a message box to the effect that the folder is associated with another email address. It also doesn't show as a separate email or data file in File > Info > Account Settings
- the user's email address `user@companyname.co.uk` doesn't have Read&Manage, Send As or Send on behalf of permissions in the company admin portal. They used to, but we have removed office from the computer a few times since then (see below)
- among the fixes we've tried are the standard office repair utilities - both quick and online repair - with a restart of the computer in between. Also tried manually uninstalling Office 365 and reinstalling it after a restart and update of the computer (windows 10).
- other computers in the company are set up exactly the same and working perfectly.
- other issues on the same user's outlook (which I hope are related so they can be fixed all together) include not being able to create or edit signatures (as per [that other question I mentioned earlier](https://superuser.com/questions/1662913/outlook-wont-let-me-create-signatures), not being able to output emails from other programs (error message says it can't create the ActiveX component) and outlook preview pane loading very slowly.
- it isn't specific to the PC, as exactly the same issues are cropping up when logging a different PC in to the same domain user.

Anyone who can suggest a fix to this has my eternal gratitude.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with exchange / Microsoft 365 account? According to my experience, if you enable the online archive for the mailbox, there would be a folder added in your mailbox and we couldn't close it, which seems to be same with yours, please kindly check if you have enable it.
[image]

If that's not your case, as a suggestion, we could also try to check the detailed information of the mailbox via press "ctrl" and right-click the outlook icon, choose connection status to check if there are any special between it and other items.